# Sticky footer adds scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm try to achive sticky footer on my page.
I try to do it by this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ .
I did waht they said there, and the footer becomes sticky, but a scroll bar added to the page , even that the content isn't get to the end of the page.
My css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -40px; 
}
#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
#footer, #wrapper:after {
    height: 40px; 
}
```

**fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/k3zvaxLs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your h1 element has a default margin that's causing your body element to be pushed down.

Replace the margin with padding by editing your h1's CSS.

```
#mainHeader h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.67em;
}
```

Here's a snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

#wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

#footer,
#wrapper:after {
  height: 40px;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
  margin: 0;
}

#searchWrapper {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#mainHeader {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#mainHeader h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.67em;
}

#searchWrapper input[type=search] {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px
}

#searchWrapper input[type=submit] {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.result {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.searchResult {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.url {
  color: green;
}

.searchResult .description {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

#pagination {
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="mainHeader">
    <h1>Ami's Search Enginge</h1>
    <div id="searchWrapper">
      <form method="get">
        <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="הזן טקסט לחיפוש" />
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="חפש" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="result">
    <article class="searchResult">
      <header class="title">
        <a href="#">כותרת תוצאת חיפוש</a>
        <br />
        <span class="url">http:://www.google.co.il</span>
      </header>
      <section class="description">
        תיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור
        תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור
        תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור
        תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאורתיאור תיאור תיאור
      </section>
    </article>

    <footer id="pagination">
      <a href="#">&lt;</a>
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
      <a href="#">5</a>
      <a href="#">&gt;</a>
    </footer>
  </section>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
  All Right Reserved To Ami
</footer>
```

Comment: Oh, you can type faster than me.

Comment: thanks, it's works, I'm sorry that I can'y vote for your answer cause I'm new, but I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

To match the tutorial you have referenced you have to add:

```
* {
      margin: 0;
}
```

Once this is added to your Css, your fiddle behaves correctly

Comment: @Punit yes this is correct. However, the question referenced a specific tutorial and asked why the behaviour was not similar and what differencews there were in the code. Comparing the tutorial and the Fiddle the *{margin:0;} was the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper has a height of 100% of the body, which also has a height of 100%, but it also has a top margin, making the total outer height greater than the height of the window!

Now you may think the body has its margins set to 0, but there is the problem of collapsing margins: the first h1 in #mainHeader in #wrapper has its default margins, so its parent gets those margins too.

Solution: set the top-margin of the h1 to 0 as well.

```css
#mainHeader h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/k3zvaxLs/1/).

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Explain please!

Comment: You probably meny `overfow-y`, but never mind, it's not a good solution, because it's just hides the scroll bar buy you don't see the footer at all

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)